# InvalidOperationException: The property 'ENTITY.ANY_Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project in C# to build hospital application help nurses to record daily caring services for there patients.

So I have 4 entities:

1. Nurses
2. Patients
3. CaringType
4. Carings

In `Caring` table nurse will record the service by adding the (`Nurse_id, Patient_id, CaringType_id`, and other information)

[image]

I have 3 relations in this table. I write the database and this is the diagram:

[image]

And this is the `Caring` model class:

```
namespace E_NurseJobs2.Models
{
    public class Caring : IEntityBase
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        public string Descreption { get; set; }

        //Relations

        [Display(Name = "Nurse")]
        public int Nurses_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Nurses_id")]
        public Nurses Nurses { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Service")]
        public int CaringType_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CaringType_Id")]
        public CaringType CaringType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Patient")]
        public int Patient_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Patient_Id")]
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in `AppDbContext` I wrote those lines:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Caring>()
                .HasKey(am => new {
                                    am.Id,
                                    am.Patient_Id,
                                    am.Nurses_id,
                                    am.CaringType_Id
                                  });
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public DbSet<Caring> Caring { get; set; }
public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
public DbSet<Nurses> Nurses { get; set; }
public DbSet<CaringType> CaringType { get; set; }
```

So.. now I can add a new `caring` record successfully.

But when I try to 'EDTI' that record, I got this error message:

[image]

Note: the value of error changing when I change the updated values (patient or nurse or caring type) but other values no problem:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Caring.Nurses_id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Caring.Patient_Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Caring.CaringType_Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

What I need to edit? I think I make mistake in `AppDbContext` code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed those lines and then It's work...

```html
   modelBuilder.Entity<Caring>().HasKey(am => new
            {
                am.Id,
                am.Patient_Id,
                am.Nurses_id,
                am.CaringType_Id
            });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```